# NextAuth.js getSession in API works with GET, fails with POST

Tags: node.js, next-auth

## TLDR:

I found a Workaround which you can find in the answers.

The question is still open and I will accept an answer which explains why the problem occurred and how to actually deal with that.

## Problem:

I have an api which is protected by NextAuth.js `4.24.4`. It did work and for whatever reason it stopped working - I can't pin it down what changed though.

`GET` commands runs successful, `POST` fails with:

```
[next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error undefined {
  error: {},
  url: 'http://localhost:3300/api/auth/session',
  message: undefined
}
```

The [linked error message info](https://next-auth.js.org/errors#client_fetch_error) points towards to be sure config was correct. Nothing changed there, so it should still work, right?!

I did add a debug Provider but that didn't improve things either:

```
CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: {  label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        if (credentials.username === 'debug' && credentials.password === 'debug') {
          return { id: 1, name: 'Debug User', email: 'debug@example.com' }
        }
        return false
      }
    }),
```

## The API

The protected Handler is more or less like the tutorial:

```
export default async function protectedHandler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  console.log('The request to get Session', {cookies: req.cookies,  headers: req.rawHeaders})
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  try {
    var { user } = session;
    console.log('Successfully retrieved Session', {req})
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'failed to authenticate user' });
  }

  if (session) {
    const result = await startExecution(req, res, user);
    return res.send({
      content: result,
    });
  }
  console.log('Not Successfully retrieved Session', {req})
  res.status(401).json({ error: 'failed to authenticate' });
}
```

## Logs

With `GET` it's working like a charm, with `POST` it fails.

Cookies and Headers:

Identical in `GET` and `POST`

```
cookies: {
    'next-auth.csrf-token': 'SOMETOKEN',
    'next-auth.callback-url': 'http://localhost:3300/',
    'next-auth.session-token': 'SOMESESSIONTOKEN'
  },
  headers: [
    'Host',
    'localhost:3300',
    'User-Agent',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0',
    'Accept',
    '*/*',
    'Accept-Language',
    'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding',
    'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer',
    'http://localhost:3300/foo',
    'Connection',
    'keep-alive',
    'Cookie',
    'next-auth.csrf-token=<SOMETOKEN>; next-auth.callback-url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3300%2F; next-auth.session-token=<SOMESESSIONTOKEN>',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest',
    'empty',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode',
    'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site',
```

diff between the two logs `The request to get Session`:

only in `GET`:

```
headers:
    'If-None-Match',
    '"vy6cdinx812znr"'
```

only in `POST`:

```
    'Content-Type',
    'text/plain;charset=UTF-8',
    'Content-Length',
    '860',
    'Origin',
    'http://localhost:3300',
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround which I'm describing below.

I'm using getServerSession. It requires some changes though:

```
# [...nextauth].ts

import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

import { SessionStrategy } from 'next-auth/core/types';


// having authOptions separately so it can be used in API
export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
      },
      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        if (credentials.username === 'debug' && credentials.password === 'debug') {
          return { id: '1', name: 'Demo User', email: 'debug@example.com'};
        }
        return null;
      }
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt' as SessionStrategy,
  },
  jwt: {
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
  },
  pages: {
  },
  callbacks: {
  },
  events: {},
  debug: true,
}

// uses authOptions
export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

```
# api:
// added some imports
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next'
import { authOptions } from '../auth/[...nextauth]'
...

export default async function protectedHandler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
) {
  console.log('The request to get Session', {cookies: req.cookies,  headers: req.rawHeaders})

// LINE CHANGED HERE:
const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)
...
```